# How can I add a hyperlink to IEEE citations?

Tags: r, bookdown, citations

In a `bookdown` book project, I am using the IEEE bibliography and citation style,  specified as follows in `index.Rmd`:

```
biblio-style: ieeetr
csl: ieee-with-url.csl
```

The style is applied as I see the familiar "[1]" square brackets. However, at the moment the citations are plain text, which means that the user has to manually click to the References section, and go look up the number manually.

Can I turn the citations themselves into hyperlinks which point to the relevant entry in the References/bibliography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following worked:

```
link-citations: yes
```

(Didn't find this in the documentation, but in a [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/962))

Answer (score 0):

If you use the LaTeX template of IEEE trans, you can use the hyperref package to make citation clickable. And you'd include a setup to remove the squares as follows:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor={red!50!black},
  citecolor={blue!65!black},
  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
  bookmarksnumbered=true,%
  bookmarksopen=true}
```

which makes citation number dark blue and clickable. You may change the color as you see fit.